# Access-Lists and VLAN and understanding traffic flow

Tags: cisco, vlan, acl, cisco-ios-12, cisco-ios-15

I have a question that I am having a very hard time wrapping my mind around, and I think you might be able to square me away.

When applying an access list to a VLAN interface (VLAN 32) in a L3 switch, for clients that are in VLAN 32 subnet, are they seen as coming into VLAN 32 on the way to being routed, or is the traffic coming out (exiting) the VLAN 32 interface?  What about traffic coming from another VLAN?

I am trying to sort this out for the purpose of deciding on applying an access list to "in" or "out" traffic against the VLAN 32 interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is often a confusing topic for users new to SVIs as it does seem to work a bit counter intuitively. Most people have a tendency to look at the SVI as some sort of "gateway" and that traffic leaving the VLAN should be outbound and vice versa.

However, it actually works in the opposite way because the SVI is a virtual router interface. It can help to think of the SVI as a physical interface on a physical router connected to the VLAN. From the perspective of this router, traffic arriving on the interface (the SVI) from the VLAN is inbound.  Traffic from the rest of the network to the VLAN would be going out (or outbound) from the perspective of this interface.

As an example, take for instance the following SVI:

```
interface Vlan10
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group VLAN10_IN in
 ip access-group VLAN10_OUT out
```

Now, let's say I want to prevent any traffic with spoofed IP addresses from leaving this VLAN. My access list may look like the below. Notice that while this traffic is outbound from the VLAN, it is inbound to the interface and as such is an inbound ACL.

```
Sw6500#sh ip access-lists VLAN10_IN
Extended IP access list VLAN10_IN
    10 permit ip 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
    20 deny ip any any
```

If I want to limit access to this VLAN so that devices with 192.168.1.0/24 addresses are blocked but all other 192.168.0.0/16 addresses are allowed, the ACL would look something like this:

```
Sw6500#sh ip access-lists VLAN10_OUT
Extended IP access list VLAN10_OUT
    10 deny ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
    20 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
    30 deny ip any any
```

**Please Note**: These are not a complete working access lists; they are meant only as examples. While they may work in certain environments, it may create problems if you try to use it.  For instance, it will not allow traffic such as DHCP if the DHCP server is on a different VLAN.

---

One parting note, that may seem obvious but I have seen trip people up before. If the SVI has multiple subnets associated with it, you need to make sure your ACLs take this into account as traffic that passes between these subnets will be processed by the ACL even though it stays within the VLAN.

As long as you keep the concept that the SVI is an interface, this should be easy to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for a thoroughly explained and understandable answer with examples.  I am accepting this as the correct answer because it is more fully formed as a response.

Answer (score 4):

Think of all the ports in the vlan as being one port, traffic between them never hit the vlan-L3 interface.

Only traffic flowing between vlan's hit the vlan-32 ACL.

Thus traffic from vlan-X to vlan-32-host will be seen as outbound by the vlan-32 ACL.

And traffic from a host in vlan32, that hits the GW on it's way somewhere else will be inbound.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: The first sentence in this answer is only correct if you only have a single subnet assigned to the VLAN/SVI. If there is a secondary IP range,  then traffic between the subnets while staying within the VLAN will still traverse the SVI.

Comment: @Ylearn Would you consider that a "non standard" deployment?  In my experience, multiple subnets on the same VLAN is more of a fringe case (or band-aid fix) than a common case.

Comment: Depends on the environment, but I would agree it is definitely in the minority and the majority of deployments tend to use a VLAN to subnet ratio of 1:1.  Whether or not that is the case though doesn't make my comment any less true.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine yourself as the router. "In" is traffic you receive; "out" is traffic you transmit.

`ip access-group foo in` applies to traffic *received* on an interface. `... out` applies to traffic being *transmit* on an interface.

Comment: yes I get that, but in this context the traffic that is coming from the VLAN 32 subnet, at the Layer 3 Switch where the traffic is being routed, is the traffic considered going "in" or "out" of the VLAN.  What about traffic coming from VLAN 10 into VLAN 32, and vice-versa. I'll add another detail to my question that might make it more clear to answer.

Comment: @lasersauce, you only come into or out from a physical device. Never think about into or out from a VLAN.

Comment: But the ACL can be applied to the VLAN interface (virtual interface yes) as IN or OUT.  Surely there is a difference there?  Thanks in advance, this has really been a roadblock for me mentally today.

Comment: @lasersauce, the ACL is applied to a router interface (a VLAN interface is a router interface, albeit a virtual interface, but still a router interface), and the in or out is ALWAYS from the router's perspective. This is something many people have a hard time wrapping their heads around. Never, ever, think of it from anything but the perspective of the router itself. Pretend you are the router, and think about inhaling and exhaling. Your breath is from your perspective, not the perspective of the atmosphere, balloon, straw, or whatever else you are breathing from and to.

Comment: whether or not the in or out is from the router perspective i'm asking from the perspective of the vlan itself.  traffic on subnet 32 being routed out of vlan 32 into another subnet or from another subnet on that same L3 switch into vlan 32.  in _those_ cases how is the traffic being seen ,respectively.  the ACL is set for either **in** or **out**

Comment: so i think it there is something missing from these explanations so far.  one couldn't expect a behavior of an ACL being applied to "in" for instance without knowing the context of the traffic flowing through the vlan (as representative of "in" or "out" flow).I definitely get the general "you are the router, now stick your arms out" analogy, I just don't see it applying here as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

vlan32 has a virtual vlan interface,
all traffic originating from vlan32 need to go out of this vlan will send traffic to vlan32's virtual interface, from the virtual interface perspective, these traffic are IN

traffic originating from other vlan like vlan 40 and need to go to vlan32, will need to use vlan32's interface as a relay, these traffic will go out of vlan32's virtual interface to go to vlan32, so these traffic from vlan32's interface perspective, they are OUT